# Hibernate + Db2 + StoredProcedure call, pass NULL value

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, db2, jpa

Is it possible to pass a null value in a stored procedure call using Hibernate and Javax.Persistence?

I'm trying to do it in this way:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("MY_PROCEDURE_NAME");
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_lease_null_me", Integer.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);
storedProcedure.setParameter("p_lease_null_me", null);
storedProcedure.execute();
```

But DB2 tells me: "missing mandatory parameter".

Any ideas?

Thanmks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look like a DB2 error; more likely it is the procedure logic that rejects a null value.

Comment: that was my first idea, but unfortunately there is no logic in procedure that doesn't allow null values for that parameter.